# NodeJS VM is not calling callback ? any other way to do same thing?

Tags: node.js

I am trying some examples with nodejs vm, Please refer following LOCs.

```
var vm = require('vm');
var jsonObject = {
    "yahoo" : 200
}

var context = {
    jsonObjectToPopulate: jsonObject,
    result: null, // this will be populated in code execution
    setTimeout : setTimeout,
    done : function(){
        console.log(context.result);
    },
    next : function(data){
        console.log('data = '+data);
        this.result = data;
        this.done();
    }
};

var jsCode = "var customFun = function(jsonObjectToPopulate){ " +
                                "setTimeout(function(){" +
                                  "next(300)}, 3000);" +
                                "};" +
                                "customFun(jsonObjectToPopulate);";
vm.runInNewContext(jsCode, context);
```

and logs are

```
data = 300
/Users/alokguha/dev/microflow/issues/1717/nodetest/vm/vmTest.js:21
        this.done();
             ^

TypeError: this.done is not a function
    at context.next (/Users/alokguha/dev/microflow/issues/1717/nodetest/vm/vmTest.js:21:14)
    at null._onTimeout (evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:56)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:89:15)
```

Node Version :  v4.0.0

so my questions are

1. Why "done" is not recognized as function ?
2. Ultimately I want to wait till VM returns me result from async code, so is it right way to do or any better way to achieve same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `done` is not recognized as a function is because `this` inside the vm context is the global object and the `context` properties are not inserted as globals but instead as local context variables.

Comment: how about the approach ? Do you think its right way to solve this kind of problems ?